# "moving attributes" to attribute set programmatically

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

Is it possible to add a php file in root directory of magento?

```
$attribute_set_name = 'your attribute set name here';
$group_name = 'your attribute group here';
$attribute_code = 'your attribute code here';

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

//-------------- add attribute to set and group
$attribute_set_id = $setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_name);
$attribute_group_id = $setup->getAttributeGroupId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, $group_name);
$attribute_id = $setup->getAttributeId('catalog_product', $attribute_code);

$setup->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId='catalog_product',$attribute_set_id, $attribute_group_id, $attribute_id);
```

I ran this code, but there is an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getResourceConfig() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php on line 131

Comment: Have u included `Mage.php`

Comment: sounds like you need to include the app/magento.php file. see this article for more details: http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/run-magento-code-externally/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always suggest doing this sort of thing via a module's set-up scripts. For full details on set-up script [see](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/), but for what you need something like the following should work.

```
<?php
/* @var $this Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup */
$this->startSetup();

$attribute_set_name = 'your attribute set name here';
$group_name = 'your attribute group here';
$attribute_code = 'your attribute code here';

//-------------- add attribute to set and group
$attribute_set_id=$this->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_name);
$attribute_group_id=$this->getAttributeGroupId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, $group_name);
$attribute_id=$this->getAttributeId('catalog_product', $attribute_code);

$this->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId='catalog_product',$attribute_set_id, $attribute_group_id, $attribute_id);

$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: How to do it for bulk update